# ASP .NET GridView not showing sorting arrows

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have the following Gridview. I need sorting arrows in every column header for sorting. I have set AllowSorting property to true.But it is not showing the arrows.Additionally, I added SortExpression to template fields .Still it is not showing the sorting arrows. I couldn't understand the issue. How can I fix this issue? 
The code is given below

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvCatReport" runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
              ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
              AllowPaging="True"
              AllowSorting="true"
              OnPageIndexChanging="dgvCatReport_PageIndexChanging"
              PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"
              PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom"
              PageSize="10"
              CssClass=" table table-striped  table-hover"
              AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
              PagerStyle-CssClass="bs-pagination">
    <columns>
        <asp:templatefield headertext="Category Name" sortexpression="CatName">
            <itemtemplate>

                <h5><%# Eval("CatName") %></h5>

            </itemtemplate>
            <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
            <itemstyle width="200px" />
        </asp:templatefield>

        <asp:templatefield headertext="Total Views" sortexpression="ReportCount">
            <itemtemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("ReportCount") %></span>

            </itemtemplate>
            <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
            <itemstyle width="75px" />
        </asp:templatefield>


        <asp:templatefield headertext="Daily Views" sortexpression="DailyCount">
            <itemtemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("DailyCount") %></span>

            </itemtemplate>
            <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
            <itemstyle width="75px" />
        </asp:templatefield>

        <asp:templatefield headertext="Weekly Views" sortexpression="WeeklyCount">
            <itemtemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("WeeklyCount") %></span>

            </itemtemplate>
            <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
            <itemstyle width="75px" />
        </asp:templatefield>

        <asp:templatefield headertext="Monthly Views" sortexpression="MonthlyCount">
            <itemtemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("MonthlyCount") %></span>

            </itemtemplate>
            <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
            <itemstyle width="75px" />
        </asp:templatefield>
    </columns>

    <%--   <pagersettings mode="NumericFirstLast" position="TopAndBottom"></pagersettings>

    <pagerstyle backcolor="White" cssclass="pgr"></pagerstyle>--%>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Asp.net grid provides default images for sorting. But you can still use a custom approach to show images.

set the Gridview properties

```
SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc"
SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc"
```

Add css classes:

```
th.sortasc a  
{
   display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
   background:url("images/icons/ascArrow.png") no-repeat;
}

th.sortdesc a 
{
   display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
  background:url("images/icons/descArrow.png") no-repeat;
}
```